# map not a function при выборе option в dropDown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`TypeError: serviceName.map is not a function` сам компонент рендерится, но при выборе опшина, ломается.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  makeStyles
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import '@material/react-select/dist/select.css';
import Select, {
  Option
} from '@material/react-select';

export default class SelectService extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      serviceName: []
    };
  }

  getServices = _ => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/prices')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => this.setState({
        serviceName: response.data
      }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getServices();
  }

  renderServices = ({
      id_service,
      title
    }) =>
    <
    Option key = {
      id_service
    }
  value = {
    title
  } > {
    title
  } < /Option>

  render() {
    const {
      serviceName
    } = this.state
    return ( <
      Select className = "select"
      label = 'Выберите Желаемую Услугу'
      value = {
        serviceName
      }
      onChange = {
        (evt) => this.setState({
          serviceName: evt.target.value
        }, () => console.log(this.state.serviceName))
      } >
      {
        serviceName.map(this.renderServices)
      } <
      /Select>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Не очень в реакте понимаю, но судя по всему `serviceName` не является массивом. Если вы из DOM забираете, то нужно сначала привести `serviceName` к нормальному JS-массиву. Из дома возвращаются коллекции, что не совсем JS-массив, а потому и методов типа `map` там нет.

Comment: `response.data` - не массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При текущей реализации и массив вариантов, и выбранное значения хранятся в одном поле в `state.serviceName`. После выставления значения, в `serviceName` оказывается строка. Нужно разделить

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  makeStyles
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import '@material/react-select/dist/select.css';
import Select, {
  Option
} from '@material/react-select';

export default class SelectService extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      serviceNames: [], // варианты
      serviceName: '' //  значение
    };
  }

  getServices = _ => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/prices')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => this.setState({
        serviceNames: response.data
      }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getServices();
  }

  renderServices = ({
      id_service,
      title
    }) =>
    <
    Option key = {
      id_service
    }
  value = {
    title
  } > {
    title
  } < /Option>

  render() {
    const {
      serviceNames, serviceName
    } = this.state
    return ( <
      Select className = "select"
      label = 'Выберите Желаемую Услугу'
      value = {
        serviceName
      }
      onChange = {
        (evt) => this.setState({
          serviceName: evt.target.value
        }, () => console.log(this.state.serviceName))
      } >
      {
        serviceNames.map(this.renderServices)
      } <
      /Select>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```